# Can't access Django server from browser

Tags: networking, django-runserver

I am working on a centOS7 server, I created a project and used `python manage.py runserver` command.
From a browser on my local machine, I cannot access the `localhost:8000` address.

I tried precising the address like
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Added also '*' to the **ALLOWED HOSTS** in **settings.py**

Nothing worked. I still can't access from the browser.

YOUR HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to access it within the server? If you can, then it is pretty much a networking issue. Check the firewall/router settings in your local network.

Comment: How can I try to access it within the server since there is no browser?
Sorry to ask, but I'm not familiar with centOS.

Comment: Afaik `curl` is pre-installed in CentOS 7.  You can run `curl http://localhost:8000` to see if you can get a valid response.

Comment: The output of that command seems to be the source code of the page

Comment: So yes, this means the Django server is up. There seems to be something between your server and client preventing them to talk with each other.

Comment: I added the machine's IP address in the firewall whitelist IPs of the server. And added '*' in **ALLOWED_HOSTS** BUT STILL NO ACCESS 
Any other idea?

Comment: Note that I can ping from my machine to the server's address but cannot ping from server to the machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone experiences the same issue, the solution was to open port 8000 on server's firewall.

Now I can access the server's address from my system.